# Как перенести сайт (html/css/js) на хостинг?

Tags: javascript, html, css, хостинг, перенос

решил для практики написать свой первый сайт и выложить его на бесплатном хостинге (чисто чтобы проверить). Но, что-то у меня ничего не получилось. Я создал хостинг чистого сайта, но не знаю как перенести на него файлы (точнее, собственно, сам сайт). Скачал FileZilla, но всё равно не очень понятно.
Простите за тупой вопрос, я всё это дело всего месяц учу, много чего не понимаю. За помощь, заранее, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Читайте в документации вашего хостинга

Comment: От хостинга после регистрации должны приходить данные как к нему подключаться, или это будет написано в админке. Или в админке будет файловый менеджер типа проводника. Как пользоваться FileZilla есть в интернете, первая же ссылка по "Как пользоваться FileZilla".

Comment: FileZilla нужен если Вы используете VPS, к примеру А так используйте эту инструкцию, суть примерно одинакова: [Как разместить файлы сайта в ISPmanager
](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/kak-razmestit-sayt-na-hostinge/kak-razmestit-sayt-v-ispmanager)